# Modify column values to that they are in order

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a very special problem that I'd like to solve in SQL. I need to make sure that optionOrder for the same questionID goes from 0-[any number].

So for example the rows with **questionID = 18386**, their **optionOrder** are right now *1,2,3,4*. They need to be ***0,1,2,3***.

Also if the rows are like this **1,2,4**, it needs to be *0,1,2*

I'm sorry for the incorrect grammars.

[image]

Comment: So, what do you want to do? renumber the options after ordering them ?

Comment: maybe leave them the way they are, and harness the power of the `order by` clause

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: @AHocevar I want to update the table so that **optionOrder** ALWAYS goes from 0-[1|2|3|4] and so on.

Comment: the optionOrder is always `0-[1|2|3|4] and so on` if you use the right `order by` clause, without screwing up other dependent child tables that rely on `id` that you just messed up by doing an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with variables:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @q := -1;

update table t
    set optionorder = (case when @q = questionid then (@rn := @rn + 1)
                            when (@q := questionid) is not null then (@rn := 0)
                            else -1 -- should never happen
                       end)
    order by questionid, optionorder;
```

Because of the `order by`, you need to set the variables outside the `update`.

Comment: Works perfect! 
I've fiddled with variables in my last attempt but I never managed to the get if statement working, thank you a lot!